# Resetting a number input to a specific value if edit permission is false

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mantine

```js
      <NumberInput
        min={1}
        max={31536000}
        defaultValue={parseInt(value)}
        onSelect={() => {
          setModalOpen(true);
          return;
        }}
        onChange={(e) => {
          console.log(isGuildPremium);
          if (isGuildPremium) {
            console.log(1);
            handleChange(e);
          }
          setModalOpen(true);
        }}
        value={saveEnabled.newSettings.cooldown}
      />
```

Hey. I'm trying  to make it so only certain users can edit this  mantine `NumberInput`. If they do not have permission I display a modal on the `on select` and `on change` event. However, if the user clicks the `NumberInput` `up arrow` or `down arrow` they are able to briefly change the value before  the modal pops up.

To fix this I have tried to add a default `value`  prop which will set the value to their current value  before  the change. However, this does not seem to rerun every  time  the pages  state is changed.

I  cannot simply `disable` the component, because I would like a popup modal to appear when the user clicks on it. If the component is marked as `disabled` then I cannot use the `onClick` event.

How would I go about fixing this as  I  am out of  ideas.

Comment: why don't you disable this input if it is not accessible for user?

Comment: Because  I would like a modal to appear  if they click on it, and  this component does not have an `onClick` event which works when the  component is disabled.

Sorry. I should have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: even if they use the up or down arrow, onChange event will be triggered right? in the onChange event handler just reset it to its default value and add the logic for showing the dialog

Comment: What about setting min and max value to the default value for the users without the right to edit? This should disable the arrows but not disable the input itself